# Does it counts as a REST?

Tags: java, php, rest

I am trying to figuring out about REST method. I watched few videos from google conference about REST technology but what I saw was app's implementation of connectivity with database. So I would like to know if my code would count as a REST.

PHP code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","*****","********");
mysql_select_db("********");
$cname = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['cname']);
$q=mysql_query("SELECT mdl_course_sections.summary FROM mdl_course, mdl_course_sections WHERE mdl_course.id = mdl_course_sections.course AND mdl_course.fullname = '$cname' AND mdl_course_sections.section > 0");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[]=$e;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

JAVA code:

```
public class CourseSegmentsActivity extends ListActivity{

String courseName = null;
String segmentName = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    courseName = i.getStringExtra("courseName");

    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> myCoursesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cname",""+courseName));

    InputStream is = null; 
    String result = null;
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("****************");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-10"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();

            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

try{
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    for(int ii=0;ii<jArray.length();ii++){
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(ii);
            segmentName = json_data.getString("summary");

            HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("summary", segmentName);
            myCoursesList.add(map);
    }
} catch(JSONException e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myCoursesList,R.layout.course_segments_list_layout,
        new String[] {"summary"}, new int[] { R.id.name});

setListAdapter(adapter);


}
}
```

If not what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are NOT. if you follow REST standards, you should be using http protocol efficiently. As per REST standard,

if you are reading data - use GET 
if you are reading meta-data - use HEAD 
if you are writing data - use POST
if you are modifying data - use PUT
if you are deleting - use DELETE,

please refer to the w3c specification of http protocol([RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)) for further info.

Comment: I am sending a value to phpscript which would return JSON. By the way what do you mean using http protocol efficiently? Am I missing something?

Comment: what I mean by using HTTP protocol efficiently is, generally people use only HTTP GET and POST requests most of the times and perform all the business logic in get and post methods. while http supports other kind of requests also like PUT and DELETE, which are ignored. The main idea behind REST is using all types of HTTP requests. suppose if you want to delete a record from a database, rather than putting that logic in POST, you would simply send a HTTP DELETE request to a specific URL, which will do the operation.

Answer (score 1):

No, you are using POST to retrieve data. However, POST is meant to be used to *edit existing* data.
Query strings are also rather unlikely when using REST - usually you use the URL to specify resources

Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST#RESTful_web_services

Comment: Yes, that would be more appropriate. Also have a look at the URL structure that is usually used with REST.

Comment: Ok, I will check it out. But the main question remains. Changing POST to GET will it make make it to the REST?